# Android Google Oauth: not returing to application after granting access

Tags: android, oauth, callback, android-manifest, oauth-2.0

I have a problem implementing Oauth in Android using [signpost](http://nilvec.com/implementing-client-side-oauth-on-android/) library. Everything is fine except the final part when it should return to the application itself after granting access.

Below is my activity callback declaration in manifest:

```
<activity android:name="ro.locationsApp.android.login.LoginScreenActivity" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="myCallbackHost"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And I pass the Callback URL from code like this:

```
new OAuthHelper("mySite", "secret", 
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "http://myCallbackHost");
```

Where myCallbackHost it's a real and functional link(it's also used for callback after a web site authentication - now I want mobile too).

The problem is that my android app is not called after this. I also tried

```
<data android:scheme="customScheme"/>
```

and

```
new OAuthHelper("mySite", "secret", 
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "customScheme:///");
```

but without success.

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing http with something else works.

Here is how my manifest looks now:

```
<activity android:name="ro.locationsApp.android.login.LoginScreenActivity" 
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="alex" android:host="me"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and code:

```
new OAuthHelper("mySite", "secret", 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "alex://me");
```

works like a charm.

Comment: have you checked the same in android ICS

Comment: yes, On Sony Ericsson Xperia Arc S, with ICS installed and it's working